# iOS Developer Program: Enterprise or Standard?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

What is the most elegant solution to test an application on a remote iPad?

My idea is to Host my application on a web server that is accessible by my customer, and he can then download the application and test it on his device.

The problem is that the customer must have a Provisioning Profile installed on their device.

Which is the best solution, so that I can install the profile on distant devices without needing Xcode?

For this situation which is the most effective, the iOS Developer Enterprise Program or iOS Developer Program?

How I have to proceed ?

Thank you .

Comment: I think you need the enterprise program to do this also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For that purpose the best is to use TestFlight.

https://testflightapp.com

There are a lot of guides on internet on how to use it

Comment: Rather than pay them, is it not just easier to send the prov profile via email?

Comment: is it possible to send prov profile via email ? i work in a enterprise i can have the developer program any time but i need to know which is the helpful one for my situation , the boss went to test this application any where and any time...

Comment: You dont need to send anything using TestFlight, just add your boss to the list of devices and he will receive an email automatically to register his device

Comment: Ok so to summarize, i must have an iOS Developer Enterprise Program, and To test on any device i just need to add it to the list of devices, and I don't need to connect the device to Xcode to install the prov profile, and it will work ?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need the Enterprise license. Just a personal. It's all about the number of devices. Personal gets you 100 devices. All the rest is correct. You upload to TestFlight. Then he gets an email which prompts him to install prov profile and then install app so he can run it.

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely agree with Antonio's recommendation of TestFlightApp.

To answer the question of enterprise versus developer, I would suggest you consider how the final product will need to be distributed, whether it will be internal to an organization, or available on the App Store.

The Enterprise program has a few extra administrative hurdles to complete for membership.

Comment: The final product will be distributed in house not available on the app store

Comment: To deploy an application on App store, appel asks for too much perfection side codes, if it is not the case, and it is practical with app store that will be a good solution (for "any where and any time" )